# When to decide to change the scope of a Grails controller

Tags: grails, scope

Default scope for Grails controller is `prototype` i.e. a new controller will be created for each request (recommended for actions as Closure properties)

Two more scopes are supported by controllers:

`session` - One controller is created for the scope of a user session

`singleton` - Only one instance of the controller ever exists (recommended for actions as methods)

When should I use which scope? When can I make a decision of changing the scope? In what scenario?

Answer (score 10):

`Prototype` and `session` scope means that you can store request/session specific state within controller fields. This however is not a recommended practice and should be avoided.

If you follow common practice and avoid state in controllers you can easily go with the `singleton` scope (which is the default in Spring Web MVC controllers).

If you have state in your controllers you have to go with `prototype` or `session` scope.

In general I would recommend not to mix different scopes for controllers.  It can be a very painful experience if you accidently add a stateful field to a singleton controller because you are used to `prototype` scope. You won't notice this bug until multiple concurrent requests/sessions access the same field and everything breaks.

Comment: What do you mean by storing statful piece of information in the controller ? For example if I'm using the singleton and I have 4 methods which call Services with singleton scopes as well, there shouldn't be any problem with multiple users concurrently invoking the same method within the same controller ? For example uploadPhoto method/action of the same controller being called/accessed by multiple concurrent user. Can you please explain ? :)